# Getting error in requests.get()

Tags: python, session, twitter, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried to scrape my twitter account using beautifulsoup instead of using twitter APIs. I am getting an error saying invalid syntax in the payload dictionary. My code is:

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload={
":authority":"twitter.com",
":method":"POST",
":path":"/sessions",
":scheme":"https",
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"content-length":"993",
"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"cookie":"_twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCKnkoiBhAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlYjBmNmQ0NmY5NTVmMmVkNTgwYjM2NTU0YzQ2NDY4NzA6B2lkIiUwYTg3%250ANzU1MmU3ZmY3ZWE3NjAyYzIwZmU5ZjkxZWQ5OQ%253D%253D--43822fe18903b3578a1f5deaeb232a8186b75e7d;" "personalization_id"="v1_jQItTVsewWTebwVuukbh6g=="; "guest_id"="v1%3A151667100176659384"; "external_referer=padhuUp37zjgzgv1mFWxJzx4vPNPpMnZ52M34anUtp0%3D|0|8e8t2xd8A2w%3D"; "ct0"="6d7781aae304f30bb5d6d0d64fc34ffe"; "_ga"="GA1.2.1441535218.1516671002"; "_gid"="GA1.2.1585412472.1516671002"; "_gat"="1",
"origin":"https://twitter.com",
"referer":"https://twitter.com/login",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36",
"username":"aaaaaaa",
"password":"ppppppp",
"authenticity_token":"40a1cc3105efeb2f1a978cf97502bc4e8f97580b"

}


res = requests.get("https://twitter.com/login",data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
for item in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
    print(item.text)
```

I am getting error saying "invalid syntax" at "cookie" part in payload. What is the mistake there? Please help me.

**UPDATE:**
I have kept '' on cookie part like this.

```
"cookie":'"_twitter_sess"="BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCKnkoiBhAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlYjBmNmQ0NmY5NTVmMmVkNTgwYjM2NTU0YzQ2NDY4NzA6B2lkIiUwYTg3%250ANzU1MmU3ZmY3ZWE3NjAyYzIwZmU5ZjkxZWQ5OQ%253D%253D--43822fe18903b3578a1f5deaeb232a8186b75e7d;" "personalization_id"="v1_jQItTVsewWTebwVuukbh6g=="; "guest_id"="v1%3A151667100176659384"; "external_referer=padhuUp37zjgzgv1mFWxJzx4vPNPpMnZ52M34anUtp0%3D|0|8e8t2xd8A2w%3D"; "ct0"="6d7781aae304f30bb5d6d0d64fc34ffe"; "_ga"="GA1.2.1441535218.1516671002"; "_gid"="GA1.2.1585412472.1516671002"; "_gat"="1"'
```

But the problem is when i print the soup.prettify(), it is showing empty screen.

Comment: did you just post your session id and token publicly?

Comment: Remove the qoutes.

Comment: if i remove the quotes, i am getting syntax error

Comment: I just passed the request headers and user credentials. @Marat

Comment: @AkhilReddy so once you authenticate, this session will have an authorized user..

Comment: can u help me with how to include that? @Marat

Comment: Don't post your personal credentials online.  Removing the username and password is quite meaningless if you post your auth token and your session id anyhow.  As for your problem, since you're able to parse the res.text I'm assuming something did return.  Did you try a `res.raise_for_status()` to see what was the status returned? One thing to keep in mind, a lot of websites have dynamic contents that simple `requests` module just can't handle.  If you're just trying to use twitter maybe you should look into a twitter API instead.

Comment: @AkhilReddy ususally you just replace personal data with placeholders, jut like you did with the username and the password. Editing the post afterwards is quite meaningliness, because full history of edits is still accessible (and you will need to edit the answer, too). Since there is no anwer yet, I would suggest to delete the post and retry, with placeholders and updated description

Comment: Actually i didnt add any original credentials in this. how to see the edit history?

Comment: I am unable to see the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove quotes between your cookies

```
"_twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCKnkoiBhAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlYjBmNmQ0NmY5NTVmMmVkNTgwYjM2NTU0YzQ2NDY4NzA6B2lkIiUwYTg3%250ANzU1MmU3ZmY3ZWE3NjAyYzIwZmU5ZjkxZWQ5OQ%253D%253D--43822fe18903b3578a1f5deaeb232a8186b75e7d; personalization_id=v1_jQItTVsewWTebwVuukbh6g==; guest_id=v1%3A151667100176659384; external_referer=padhuUp37zjgzgv1mFWxJzx4vPNPpMnZ52M34anUtp0%3D|0|8e8t2xd8A2w%3D; ct0=6d7781aae304f30bb5d6d0d64fc34ffe; _ga=GA1.2.1441535218.1516671002; _gid=GA1.2.1585412472.1516671002;_gat=1"
```

Comment: i am getting no error but still if i print the soup object, it is empty

Comment: I removed the quotes and executed the code. I am getting empty result. There is no change in the code.